# Can one use a chess clock on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Can one use an analog chess clock on Shabbat?
This would require setting the timers, and continually starting and stopping it until the little red flag falls (no buzzer)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64420/is-it-forbidden-to-use-a-sand-timer-on-shabbos

Comment: Does it make a satisfying "click" when you hit the button, audibly alerting your opponent that it's now their move?